# How to convert MS Access Database to Mysql with french characters

Tags: ms-access, mysql

i have ms access database with some french character and i want to convert it  to mysql database,i have tried some free db converter software for conversion ,and i got the converted database but when i checked data in phpmyadmin its showing some incorrect char (such as ?) in place of french character.Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use utf-8 collation do you still get issues...?
I used the MySQL Migration Toolkit (*the old one but is fine for Access 2003*) and it worked just fine with Greek characters using utf8.
You can find the MySQL Migration Toolkit [here](http://downloads.mysql.com/archives/migration/)
If you encounter issues with Java check my solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30590498/1321707)